# How to perform different Device Behaviour [ sound or vibrate] on some action occur in iOS8+?

Tags: ios8, notifications, iphone-vibrate

I want to perform different device behaviour like sound,vibrate on some action occur.

exa. Once notification (`Interactive notification`) is arrive in the app and device will start vibrating or some different device behaviour will occur.I am using VoIP push service in my app. Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my answer.
If i want to vibrate device on some action occur than this one line of code i need to set and to make it vibrate more second i need to put in a loop.

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate)
```

But this is depends on user device settings.